# Re: Billing - are subscriptions on Azure like Droplets on DO?

Tags: azure, resource-management

I have four websites running on a single Linux VM on Azure. I want to deploy 4 (smaller) Linux VMs on Azure, and put each of these sites on one.

I would like them to be seperately billed, as they are effectively four different customers. On Azure, do you think this is best done by having 4 x subscriptions, or is that control better done via Resource Groups or otherwise?

Following that, am I correct in understanding the subscriptions can be transferred to other Azure customers, like Droplets on Digital Ocean? e.g. if each of the four customers opened their own Azure account, I could transfer the subscription for their VM to their Azure account at a later stage.

I was hoping an experienced Azure user with multiple active subscriptions might offer (subjective) advice/opinion? I am a Digital Ocean user normally, and know how organise this with DO Droplets.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at your billing at both the subscription level or the resource group, so for that scale of workload I would be looking to separate them at the resource group level, it's going to make management easier not having to manage multiple subscriptions. 
We use both subs and resource groups for separation. Generally we separate at the sub level either where we know we are going to hit limits on the number of a certain resource, or where we want to be able to clearly show a hard delineation between one set of resources and another (and to be honest that's really more of a perception thing).

The transferring of subscriptions really depend on the type of subscription it is. If it is a normal pay as you go sub then yes you can transfer to another owner. If you have an EA subscription you can only transfer to another owner in the same enrollment. See [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-subscription-transfer) for more details.

If you are going to resell Azure services a lot then one thing you may also want to look at is [CSP](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/offers/ms-azr-0145p/), which allows you to own the subscription but give the client more control.